# How to convert String to spark.sql.Column for querying?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

The situation is that I want to give the user the ability to filter out data from a dataframe. Progammatically I can do it fine, like this.

```
val filter = col("SomeColA") > 0.1 && col("SomeColB") > 0.2

val queriedData = sqlContext.read.format("csv").
 option("header", "true").
 option("delimiter", "\t").option("inferSchema","true").
 load(filePath).where(filter)
```

However, here I want the user to provide the filter itself, using for example a text box. In other words, I want to be able to turn a string into its equivlant `spark.sql.Column` value. For example, I want the user to be able to specify `$"SomeCol" > 0.1` here in the form of a String. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can simply use the version of `where` that takes the condition expression as a string i.e. `.where("SomeCol > 0.1")`. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#where-java.lang.String-

Comment: Works indeed. But how do I apply and/or conditions with different columns. For example, how can I do the equivalent of col("A") > 0.1 && col("B") > 0.2

Comment: It is possible to put any SQL condition there e.g. `.where("A > 0.1 AND B > 0.2")` or even write the full query `sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE A > 0.1 AND B > 0.2")`